# How to get at the rgb values within a pcl::PointXYZRGB cloud

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying write a simple code to segment a red coloured tile on a desk, in rviz I can visualize the point cloud seen by the kinect and I have observed that it's rgb colour ranges from ~2.18*10^-38 to ~2.24*10^-38. I want to filter this out and find it's position.

So I have a loop on the coloured_cloud to fill the coloured_tile if it finds any points with this specific colour. With my desk rgb value at ~1.8*10^-38, an if-statement should segment the specific colour out and put it into coloured_tile.

```
double maxVal_RT = pow(2.18,-38.0);
double minVal_RT = pow(2.24,-38.0);

for (size_t l = 0; l < coloured_cloud->points.size(); l++) 
            {   
            if(coloured_cloud->points[l].rgb > minVal_RT && coloured_cloud->points[l].rgb < maxVal_RT)
                    coloured_tile->points.push_back(coloured_cloud->points[l]); 
            }
```

But this doesn't work and when I use ROS_INFO to see what these values it has for minVal_RT and maxVal_RT it says 0.00000 and coloured_cloud->points[l].rgb prints out nans.

It appears that maybe these values are too small to work with the way I am, is there another way to accomplish this? I just want to simply segment out this point cloud of a known, and static, colour.

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57943/how-to-get-at-the-rgb-values-within-a-pcl::pointxyzrgb-cloud/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which version of the PCL are you using? if i remember it correctly, for PCL >= 1.4, you can directly access the point's r,g,b value by

```
pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
point.r = red;
point.g = green;
point.b = blue;
```

where red, green and blue are all uchar ranging from 0 to 255.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-14**:
I'm running 1.7, but when I use rviz's 'select' to look at points in my region of interest it gives me their .rgb values, is there a way to get them to display the r g b values separately?  (I'm referring to the value in the bottom right corner of this image: [http://i.imgur.com/zHklFOB.png](https://i.imgur.com/zHklFOB.png))

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2013-03-14**:
sorry, i don't know how to show that in rviz

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-15**:
It's ok, I went ahead and just used the .r,.g.,b. values like you suggested. And I believe all you need to do is click the 'Select' tab in the top-left corner of rviz and select a point cloud to bring up that information, in case you wanted to see how the .rgb or xyz values! Thanks again yangyangcv

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- First: 2.18*10^-38 is completely different from 2.18^-38
- Second: There is no single continuous rgb-value. Its a combination of 3 single indepedent values (red, green, blue) and has to be treated as such.

If you want a continuous indicator of "color", you should convert the rgb-values to something like [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and use the `hue` component (together with appropriate saturation and value of course). Read this [documentation of the pcl::PointXYZRGB Struct](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html) to understand, why they packed rgb into a float and how to access the single rgb-values of the point. (Either by recasting and bit shifting or directly by using the .r, .g, .b accessors)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-14**:
Ahh, thank you Ben. I was hoping to just get around switching it to a hue, and just do a really quick segmentation of the point cloud based on values that I observed in rviz (referring to my picture in the comment of yangyangcv's answer). Thanks for the answer!